# How to define an arraylist of nested class objects in Java?

Tags: java, nested-class

I have the following class definition:

```
public class kdtrees{
 ...
  public static class DataPoints{
  ... 
  }

}
```

I can create objects of the inner class using:

```
kdtrees.DataPoint point = new kdtrees.DataPoint();
```

I want to make `point`, an `ArrayList` so that I can instantiate multiple objects of the inner class. How can I do it?

Comment: You want to make an ArrayList of DataPoint objects?

Comment: Its the exact same with a nested class as it is with any other. ArrayList<DataPoints> list; or ArrayList<kdtrees.DataPoints> list;

Comment: Besides `kdtrees` should be called `KdTrees`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<kdtrees.DataPoint> list = new ArrayList<kdtrees.DataPoint>();
list.add(new kdtrees.DataPoint());
```

Comment: can you please tell me, how to get object of inner class while retrieving the list

Answer (score 1):

```
List<kdtrees.DataPoint> list = new ArrayList<kdtrees.DataPoint>();
points.add(new kdtrees.DataPoint());
```

Don't understand your problem, sorry.